# How to sort more than 1 digit number by pointer?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

What I want to ask is, in the below program in method sorting (void sortArrayPointers(char *p[]))   only works for 1 digit numbers. (for example if I give 6,1,3,2 as input it sorts as 1,2,3,6 as expected.) But when I give 2 digit numbers or more, It only sorts according to first digit and doesn't care the other bits. I understand this indeed because my pointer points to 1st char so it only counts 1st one. I want the program to sort more than 1 digit numbers also. What am missing here? How can I make a pointer to take into account all bits?

NOTE : SOLVED: Used this expression instead of the post:    if (strcmp(p[j], p[j+1])>0)    in sort function.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

    void sortArrayPointers(char *p[]);
    int getUserInput();
    void printContent(char *p[], int  counter);

    char *myDynamicArray[25];
    char buffer[80];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int countSort;

    void sortArrayPointers(char *p[]){

    char *temp;
    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < countSort; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < countSort - 1; j++)
        {
            if (*p[j]>*p[j + 1])
            {
                temp = p[j];
                p[j] = p[j + 1];
                p[j + 1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

 }

    //Input
    int getUserInput(){

    int count;

    puts("Enter integers, press enter to end");

    while ((i < 25) && (fgets(buffer, 80, stdin) != 0) && (buffer[0] != '\n'))  //fgets adds a \n at the end

    {
        //allocate pointers space according to buffer
        if ((myDynamicArray[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1)) == NULL)
            return -1;
        //copy buffer to allocated space
        strcpy(myDynamicArray[i++], buffer);

    }

    //print the contents
    count = i;

    return count;

    }

    //prints the contents of the pointer to character array
    void printContent(char *p[], int  counter){

    int k = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < counter; k++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p[k]);
    }

    }
    //main method
    int main(void){

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;

    count = getUserInput(myDynamicArray);
    countSort = count;
    puts("Before sort:\n");
    printContent(myDynamicArray, count);

    sortArrayPointers(myDynamicArray);
    puts("After sort:\n");
    printContent(myDynamicArray, count);

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: You could start by storing them as numbers instead of characters.

Comment: In fact I want to sort also some words. How should I do them both?

Comment: While the function `strdup` is not in standard C, it's still available from about all compiler/standard library suppliers. Use it. And what's with all the global variables? Those are especially problematic since you shadow some of them as local variables in the `main` function.

Comment: As for your "sorting" function, you only compare the first character of each string (because you use the dereference operator `*`). Maybe you want to read about the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function?

Comment: All my functions use the same so I put them on top to become available to all. Maybe I made a mistake there too.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I tried strcmp. And it works as expected! Thx so much. I used this "if (strcmp(p[j], p[j+1])>0)"

Comment: Also If you tell me more about shadowing or give me a link It would be nice. Never heard of it before.

Comment: shadowing = you have local variables with names the same as global variables